# How do you prove the greatest order of a group $(\mathbb{Z}/n ,+)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing

We can assume that $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Logically you would say that the greatest order of the group is equal to $n$, I know this is true for smaller groups such as $(\mathbb{Z}/3, +)$, $(\mathbb{Z}/8, +)$ etc. I am assuming that the group $(\mathbb{Z}/n, +) = \{\overline{0}, ..., \overline{n-1}\}$ but from here on I don't know how to prove that the greatest order of an element in group $(\mathbb{Z}/n, +)$ is equal to $n$.

Comment: The group $(\mathbb Z / K, +)$ is cyclic of order $K$, as can be shown by investigating the element $1$ modulo $K$. The result you want follows from the defining property of a cyclic group.

Comment: For the OP: $K$ usually denotes a field. I've replaced it by $n$.

Comment: I think you mean that $<1> = \{\overline{0}, ..., \overline{K-1}\}$ and thus the entire group $(\mathbb{Z}/K, +)$ forms and that it is therefore a cyclic group? So suppose you have element $1 \in (\mathbb{Z}/K, +)$ and it forms a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}/K, +)$ because $1$ is a generator. Is it then the case that the order of the subgroup: $<1>$ is equal to the order of the entire cyclic group $(\mathbb{Z}/K, +)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g\in \Bbb{Z}_n$. By Lagrange's Theorem, $|g|=|\langle g\rangle|$ divides $n$. Hence the largest order of an element in $\Bbb{Z}_n$ is at most $n$.

Next, note that the order of $\bar{1}$ in $\Bbb{Z}_n$ is $n$. Therefore the largest order of an element in $\Bbb{Z}_n$ is $n$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It may be a stupid question, but how can you prove that the largest order of an element in $\Bbb{Z}_n$ is at most $n$. I understand that it is, but I don't really know how to prove it correctly.

Comment: @yungCalculator Let $k$ be a positive integer. Then $k\bar{1}=\bar{k}$. Therefore $k\bar{1}=\bar{0}$ iff $\bar{k}=\bar{0}$ iff $n$ divides $k$. Since the order of an element $g\in \Bbb{Z}_n$ is the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $kg=\bar{0}$, we conclude that the order of $\bar{1}$ is $n$.

Comment: @yungCalculator I think Alan Wang has answered your question because for all $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$, if $n\neq 0$ and $m \mid n$ then $m\le n$